# How to use different hiberante naming strategy only for a single @Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity(name = "MyTable")
@Table(name = "MyTable")
public class MyTable {
}
```

Result: `Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [my_table]`

Problem: the table is indeed named `MyTable` as is. How can I set the entity table name explicit, without having to change the global naming strategy?

Because, for all of my other entities the default hibernate naming strategy is correct (therefore I cannot change it globally).